# Java JSONObject parsed in Polymer report component

Tags: json, polymer

I have a Java class that gives me as output  JSON objects.
e.g.

```
{"date":"20170220","action":"run","eat":"banana","sleep":"20170315152644"}...
```

On the other side,
I have created the front-end with polymer 1.

> ```
>         <table>
>             <caption>Actions</caption>
>
>             <thead>
>             <tr>                     
>                 <th scope="col">date</th>
>                 <th scope="col">action</th>
>                 <th scope="col">eat</th>
>                 <th scope="col">sleep</th> 
>             </tr>
>             </thead>
>             <tbody>
>                <td>{{}}</td>
>                <td>{{}}</td>
>                <td>{{}}</td>
>                <td>{{}}</td>
>            </tbody>
>   </table>
> </my-table>
> ```

I am trying to send the JSON results from the backend to the front end.

Answer (score 2):

Hi for this you need an  component called [iron-ajax](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax), it will create an ajax call for you. When you got your result from it you can use [dom-repeat](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/elements/dom-repeat) to render your table rows (or use a predefined component for a table like [vaadin-grid](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/vaadin/vaadin-grid)).

Assuming your JSON output is an array.

```
[
    {"date":"20170220","action":"run","eat":"banana","sleep":"20170315152644"},
    ...
]
```

Your front end would look like this.

```
<my-table>
    <template>
        <iron-ajax auto url="..." handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>

        <table>
            <caption>Actions</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">date</th>
                    <th scope="col">action</th>
                    <th scope="col">eat</th>
                    <th scope="col">sleep</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
                    <tr>
                        <td>[[item.date]]</td>
                        <td>[[item.action]]</td>
                        <td>[[item.eat]]</td>
                        <td>[[item.sleep]]</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </template>
    <script>
        // omitted...
    </script>
</my-table>
```